# Keeps crashing when playing sequence on my new mega computer

Tags: eevee-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

I tried to do this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35bbyAJodEQ but right when I finished attaching the 3 render sequences, @10:55 from then on, if I played the sequence, blender just crashed, every time. I have 100,000 rain drops, vs the 200,000 he suggested.

I have a Ryzen 7 5800x, GeForce RTX 3070, with 64gb of ram and 2 tb m.2 ssd. what is going on?

Comment: did you use everything else same as he said? Can you share your blend file so that I can try it on my "mega-super" computer?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1djr9phjTWy7KVyttasV_yCFY0u7fqBuT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm, it works completely fine for me even with million of drops... and I have OC 5800X too, particle systems depends on CPU so it is probably not related to your hw, (if you are using oc, but even not overclocked version should handle 100 000 of low poly drops...) GPU shouldn't be the problem as well, it takes only 1.5GB of RAM at 1m drops... which blender version are you using? Are you using 3.0 or older?

Comment: I have the 3.0 version of blender.